# Casting to int or float depending on is_integer

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have some type `T`, and in some cases it may be, for example `char`, but I want to output its integral value, not the character. For this is have the following:

```
typedef ( std::numeric_limits< T >::is_integer ? int : float ) FormatType;
os << static_cast< FormatType >( t );
```

However this fails to compile, stating "`error C2275: 'int' : illegal use of this type as an expression`". Prefixing `int` and `float` with `typename` does not revolve the issue. What am I missing here?

The following, which I believe is equivalent, works:

```
if( std::numeric_limits< T >::is_integer )
{
    os << static_cast< int >( t );
}
else
{
    os << static_cast< float >( t );
}
```

Comment: BTW, it would be equivalent aside from the fact that the former is not valid. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

You are trying to use types as expressions. C++ simply doesn’t allow this. You can instead use so-called “compile-time `if`” via metaprogramming. For example, I believe Boost offers the following:

```
typedef if_<std::numeric_limits< T >::is_integer, int, double>::type FormatType;

os << static_cast< FormatType >( t );
```

On your other hand, your second solution works well, and the compiler will figure out that one of the branches can never be true, and eliminate it. So the performance will be the same in both cases (in fact, the exact same code should be generated).

Answer (score 2):

Try using integral promotion:

```
os << +t;
```

You'll get an `int` out of it for an integral type, or your original floating-point type if it was one.

Comment: Too obscure to be used as-is, IMHO. I’d encapsulate it in a properly named function to make the intent clear. Otherwise, very elegant.

Comment: @Konrad: Your function would need to be templated, and I think we'd be right back where we started with the original question. I don't see that it's obscure, though a small comment next to its use might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @Tomak: I've accepted Konrad's answer because it directly adresses the question, but I have actually used your approach in my code so I wish I could give more than +1; and I've added a comment to pass on the knowledge :)

Comment: @Dave: :) Glad you got your solution.

Answer (score 0):

gcc accepts it, not sure about others:

```
template<bool Expression, typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult>
  class conditional_type;

template<typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult>
class conditional_type<1, TrueResult, FalseResult> {
public:
    typedef TrueResult R;
};

template<typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult>
class conditional_type<0, TrueResult, FalseResult> {
public:
    typedef FalseResult R;
};

typedef conditional_type<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer,int,float>::R FormatType;
```

Comment: This is pretty standard template specialization, all halfway modern compilers accept this. Why are you using `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false`, though?

Comment: @Justin: I see that. The question is, *why* abuse the fact that C++ has a weak type system?

Comment: @Konrad and somebody else is likely equally inclined to question why i chose `class` in this case, rather than `struct`. some people choose `NULL`, others prefer `0`. i don't see it as abuse, but preference (and everybody has them). everybody should know these basics enough that it shouldn't noticeably affect readability. but to answer your question: i suppose the origin for the change in my case is that there are (beyond the scope of c++) several boolean types and constants -- i prefer simplicity when it comes to writing code. i don't want to use 6 variants of true and false in my (cont)

Comment: codebase, based on what i am calling. so i just keep the type and omit the use of the named constants. yes - i'll have a lot of code to fix if the definition of true and false ever change =)

Comment: @Justin: That's "just how you write"? It's silly. The definitions of `true` and `false` are never going to change, but the benefit of using them is that they do exactly what they say, and they have the expected type.

Comment: guys, i don't come here for this. find somebody else who's interested. i have better things to do. goodbye.